# Wordpress doesn't load HTML

Tags: php, filters

All,
I'm trying to have a side navigation menu that once you click on a link it basically pulls the content of that wordpress page and displays it. I've got the following code to do this:

```
$qry = "Select post_content from wp_jjfuap_posts where ID='$menu->object_id'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$resultset = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$output = apply_filters( 'the_content', $resultset['post_content'] );
```

The issue is that it doesn't translate any HTML. It simply just displays the HTML. For example, it will output the following:

```
<ul><li>Test</li><li>Another test</li></ul>
Blah
<img src=”http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/team.jpg” alt=”" width=”300″ height=”240″ /> <h2 style=”margin: 25px 0 0 0;”>Al</h2> <span class=”small”><em>Person</em></span> <p style=”text-align: justify;”>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lacinia justo quis neque da</p>
```

How can I get Wordpress to actually display the correct HTML using this method?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, "translate" the html?

Comment: @goldenapples I just means it displays the HTML like that instead of actually dislaying the image or displaying the Test and Another Test in an unordered format list.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the way I went about this and did this to solve it:

```
$page = get_page( $menu->object_id );
$output .= apply_filters( 'the_content', $page->post_content );
```

My information now shows up correctly.